# Netinfo connectionChange event listener not getting detached

Tags: react-native

I have added connectionChange event listener on splash screen componentDidMount, but it is not removed on componentwillUnmount. It is active on every page of the application. How can I detach it on componentWillUnmount.

```
componentDidMount() {
         NetInfo.addEventListener('connectionChange',
    (networkType)=> {
        this.handleFirstConnectivityChange({networkType})
    }
}

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.notificationListener.remove();
        NetInfo.removeEventListener(
            'connectionChange'
          );

}
```

Comment: Are you certain ```componentWillUnmount``` is being called?

Comment: yes i did a message alert on it. It's getting called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the same callback you used in `addEventListener` to `removeEventListener`:

```
class SomeClass extends Component {
  handleConnectivityChange = networkType => {
    //...
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.addEventListener(
      "connectionChange", 
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.removeEventListener(
      "connectionChange", 
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  }
}
```

Note that you *shouldn't* create a new arrow function wrapper when calling `addEventListener`, because you won't have a reference to that function instance, and you can't pass it to `removeEventListener` to unregister it. Instead, define the callback on the class instance, as above.

Answer (score 0):

import OfflineNotice anywhere this works fine and please note u can see this working only in a physical device, not in the simulator

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

function MiniOfflineSign() {
return (
    <View style={styles.offlineContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.offlineText}>No Internet Connection</Text>
    </View>
);
}

let currentNetwork;

NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
currentNetwork = state.isConnected;
});
const OfflineNotice = () => {
const [isConnected, setConnected] = React.useState(currentNetwork);
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe =  NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
        console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
        setConnected(state.isConnected);

    });

    return unsubscribe
}, [])

return (
<>
      {!isConnected && (<MiniOfflineSign />)}
</>
 )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
offlineContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#b52424',
    height: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 30
},
offlineText: { color: '#fff' }
});

export default OfflineNotice;
```